# 1-50 lottery game

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am a beginner Python "developer" and I was messing with Python while I was offline on vacation, so I made this lottery game. Please leave your opinions on what I should do to improve it.

```
import random
guessed=[]
correct=[]
combo=[]
numtimes=6
loop = 0
#generates 7 random numbers and adds to list
while loop < 7:
    nmbr = random.randint(1,50)
    loop += 1
    combo.append(nmbr)
combo.sort()
print("Choose seven numbers:")
#number picking system
while len(guessed) < 7:
    gnum = int(input())
    if gnum > 50:
        print("The number cant be more than 50!" + "\nEnter another one:")
        continue
    elif gnum in guessed:
        print("You already guessed that! Try again!")
        continue
    #keeps track of how much nums are inputted
    else:
        guessed.append(gnum)
    print("You need " + str(numtimes) + " more!")
    numtimes -= 1
print("Numbers drawn:")
print(*combo)
#checks for correct guesses and adds them to a correct list
for num in combo:
    if num in guessed:
        if num in correct:
            continue
        else:
            correct.append(num)
print("Your guesses:")
print(*guessed)
print("\n")
print("You guessed " + str(len(correct)))
```

Answer (score 4):

1. All your code to create 7 random numbers, i.e.:

   > ```
   > loop = 0
   > #generates 7 random numbers and adds to list
   > while loop < 7:
   >     nmbr = random.randint(1,50)
   >     loop += 1
   >     combo.append(nmbr)
   > combo.sort()
   > ```

   you can rewrite as:

   ```
   #generates 7 random numbers and adds to list
   combo = sorted(map(lambda x: random.randint(1,50), range(0,7)))
   ```

About lambda see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda

2. Calculate count or correct values:

   > ```
   > #checks for correct guesses and adds them to a correct list
   > for num in combo:
   >     if num in guessed:
   >         if num in correct:
   >             continue
   >         else:
   >             correct.append(num)
   > ```

   Rewrite as:

   ```
   correct = list(set([val for val in guessed if val in combo]))
   ```

   In this code you receive all values (`val`) from `combo`, if value (`val`) exist in `guessed`. And from all this values you create list (`correct`). `list` and `set` were used to create list with uniq values.
3. All constants (7, 50, etc) replace to variable.

Comment: Oh crap, thanks for pointing that out. I was unaware of the use of "lambda" function, so I didn't think of implementing it.

Comment: can you explain the second piece of code?

Comment: @exali he is just taking the inputs that are in the extracted random numbers and removing duplicates with `set`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make this open to human error I have one suggestion

```
while len(guessed) < 7:
    gnum = int(input())
    if gnum > 50:
```

I might rewrite that bit of code as

```
while len(guessed) < 7:
    try:
        gnum = int(input('What\'s your lucky guess??\n-->')) 
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a number')
        continue
    if gnum > 50:
```

This allows you to possibly get an input that is not a number, and when it tries to turn the string into an int and it doesn't work, it pulls a ValueError, but you're expecting a ValueError and you instead of crashing the program, you print a thing and skip the rest of that loop so nothing gets added, and it begins again at the question.